# Eclipse plugin to perform eclipse menu operation

Tags: eclipse, plugins

I want to make an eclipse plugin to perform following operation
 - Window \ Editor \ Clone
 - Close other tabs in editor.

Any help on this topic. I searched but didn't find anything relevant on this topic.

Comment: What are you asking here. We aren't going to write the entire plugin for you so you need to be much more specific about what your problem is.

Comment: I want to know how to access the menubar items and click on it.
The problem i am facing is i am new and i can't find any suitable guide / tutorial

Comment: Generally you don't access menu items and click them. You use the command service and/or the handler service to execute the underlying commands - see for example [here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseCommandsAdvanced/article.html)